# (Python) Find the indices of the values in two arrays that are equal to the values in two other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, equals, indices

I have the following 4 arrays and I want to get the indices of the values that are equal in the arrays A and X corresponding to the values in the same position in B and Y. So for the following example,

```
    import numpy as np
    A = np.asarray([400.5, 100,  700,   200,  15, 900])
    B = np.asarray([500.5, 200,  500, 600.5,   8, 999])
    X = np.asarray([400.5, 700,  100,   300,  15, 555, 900])
    Y = np.asarray([500.5, 500,600.5,   100,   8, 555, 999])
```

I want to get two arrays with the indices:

#### indAB = [0 2 4 5]

- 0 because 400.5 and 500.5 in A&B are also in X&Y in the position 0
- 2 because 700 and 500 in A&B are also in X&Y in the position 2
- 4 because 15 and 8 in A&B are also in X&Y in the position 4
- 5 because 900 and 999 in A&B are also in X&Y in the position 5

#### indXY = [0 1 4 6]

- 0, 1, 4, and 6 are found similar to indAB but with respect to X&Y instead.

where indAB are the indices of the values in A and B that are equal to the values in X and Y and indXY are the indices of the values in X and Y that are equal to the values in A and B.

This is my attempt so far:

```
    def indices(a,b):
        setb = set(b)
        ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x in setb]
        return ind

    iA = np.asarray(indices(A,X))
    iB = np.asarray(indices(X,A))
    iX = np.asarray(indices(B,Y))
    iY = np.asarray(indices(Y,B))

    def CommonIndices(a,b):
        return np.asarray(list(set(a) & set(b)))

    indAB = CommonIndices(iA,iX)
    indXY = CommonIndices(iB,iY)

    print(indAB) # returns = [0 2 4 5]
    print(indXY) # returns = [0 1 2 4 6]
```

I keep getting [0 1 2 4 6] for indXY which is incorrect. 2 is not supposed to be included because even though 600.5 is in Y and B, 200 and 100 in A and B (respectively) are not equal.

I would be very grateful if someone could offer a solution to this. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains functionality to do this kind of thing efficiently and elegantly. Memory requirements are linear, and computational requirements NlogN for this method. For the substantial arrays you are considering, the speed benefit relative to the currently accepted brute force method could easily be orders of magnitude:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy_indexed as npi

A = np.asarray([400.5, 100,  700,   200,  15, 900])
B = np.asarray([500.5, 200,  500, 600.5,   8, 999])
X = np.asarray([400.5, 700,  100,   300,  15, 555, 900])
Y = np.asarray([500.5, 500,600.5,   100,   8, 555, 999])

AB = np.stack([A, B], axis=-1)
XY = np.stack([X, Y], axis=-1)

# casting the AB and XY arrays to npi.index first is not required, but a performance optimization; without this each call to npi.indices would have to re-index the arrays, which is the expensive part
AB = npi.as_index(AB)
XY = npi.as_index(XY)
# npi.indices(list, items) is a vectorized nd-equivalent of list.index(item)
indAB = npi.indices(AB, XY, missing='mask').compressed()
indXY = npi.indices(XY, AB, missing='mask').compressed()
```

Note that you can choose how to handle missing values as well. Also take a look at the set-operations, such as npi.intersection(XY, AB); they might provider a simpler route to what it is you aim to achieve at a higher level.

Comment: Nice. It does indeed look much more efficient than the accepted answer. I don't know how you implemented `npi`. As far as I can tell, my answer is related to yours, but with vanilla Python objects.

Comment: Its a little different; npi is written in 'pure numpy', so the trick to doing set-type operations is to (arg)sort arrays and bring related items together. Therefore, O(NlogN) performance rather than the O(N) your method should have. But for many real world cases sorting turns out better than O(NlogN) since data is rarely purely random; and of course the vectorization is hard to beat.

Comment: The numpy_indexed package worked perfectly. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's always nice to talk to authors for first-hand experience on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.asarray([400.5, 100,  700,   200,  15, 900])
B = np.asarray([500.5, 200,  500, 600.5,   8, 999])
X = np.asarray([400.5, 700,  100,   300,  15, 555, 900])
Y = np.asarray([500.5, 500,600.5,   100,   8, 555, 999])

AB = np.stack([A, B], axis=-1)
XY = np.stack([X, Y], axis=-1)

eq = AB[:, np.newaxis, :] == XY[np.newaxis, :, :]
eq = np.logical_and.reduce(eq, axis=-1)

indAB, = np.where(np.logical_or.reduce(eq, axis=1))
indXY, = np.where(np.logical_or.reduce(eq, axis=0))

print("indAB", indAB)
print("indXY", indXY)
```

Output:

```
indAB [0 2 4 5]
indXY [0 1 4 6]
```

**Explanation**

`AB` and `XY` are just the arrays `A` and `B` and `X` and `Y` respectively "stacked" into two dimensional arrays. `eq` holds the all-against-all comparison of the elements in `AB` and `XY`; `np.newaxis` is used to add dimensions to `AB` and `XY` (note that `AB` gets a new dimension in position 1 and `XY` in position 0). The equality operator `==` broadcasts the arrays through their new dimensions. The first `np.logical_and.reduce` is to ensure that *both* "components" are equal (`A` to `X` and `B` to `Y`), and the `np.logical_or.reduce` operations check if there are any full equalities from `AB` to `XY` and from `XY` to `AB`. Finally, `np.where` gets the indices.

As a downside, note that this requires a boolean array of size `len(A)` x `len(X)` x 2, so if the original arrays are *very* large you might run into memory problems.

**Update**

As indicated, very large arrays could be an issue. If you want to make all the comparisons "in one go" there is not really a way around it (there size of the intermediate array is simply the number of comparisons). However, you can also run the algorithm "by pieces", for example something like this:

```
import numpy as np

MAX_SIZE = 2  # Biggest array will be MAX_SIZE x MAX_SIZE x 2

A = np.asarray([400.5, 100,  700,   200,  15, 900])
B = np.asarray([500.5, 200,  500, 600.5,   8, 999])
X = np.asarray([400.5, 700,  100,   300,  15, 555, 900])
Y = np.asarray([500.5, 500,600.5,   100,   8, 555, 999])

AB = np.stack([A, B], axis=-1)
XY = np.stack([X, Y], axis=-1)

maskAB = np.full(len(AB), False, dtype=bool)
maskXY = np.full(len(XY), False, dtype=bool)

for iAB in range(0, len(AB), MAX_SIZE):
    pAB = np.expand_dims(AB[iAB:iAB + MAX_SIZE], axis=1)
    for iXY in range(0, len(XY), MAX_SIZE):
        pXY = np.expand_dims(XY[iXY:iXY + MAX_SIZE], axis=0)
        eq = pAB == pXY
        eq = np.logical_and.reduce(eq, axis=-1)
        maskAB[iAB:iAB + MAX_SIZE] |= np.logical_or.reduce(eq, axis=1)
        maskXY[iXY:iXY + MAX_SIZE] |= np.logical_or.reduce(eq, axis=0)

indAB, = np.where(maskAB)
indXY, = np.where(maskXY)

print("indAB", indAB)
print("indXY", indXY)
```

And the output is still:

```
indAB [0 2 4 5]
indXY [0 1 4 6]
```

I'm using a `MAX_SIZE` of 2 just to show that it works in the example, but in practice you can choose it depending on the maximum amount of memory you are willing to use (e.g. for `MAX_SIZE = 10000` it should be in the order of hundreds of megabytes). `MAX_SIZE` does *not* need to be smaller the size of the arrays, nor it has to be a divisor of their size.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! That's exactly what I needed and I would have never gotten there myself haha. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @TimeExplorer No problem. I have added some explanations in case you (or anyone finding the answer) find it useful.

Comment: The arrays are indeed quite large 35182*2044207*2=143838581348. Is there a way around this that isn't too costly?

Comment: @TimeExplorer I've added a variant of the code that runs the algorithm "by pieces", it should allow you to constraint the amount of memory used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method. I dare say it's relatively clear, it should be efficient thanks to the use of sets and it only requires `O( len(A) + len(X) )` memory.

`numpy` isn't even needed, but can be used for the arrays.

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = [400.5, 100, 700, 200, 15, 900]
B = [500.5, 200, 500, 600.5, 8, 999]
X = [400.5, 700, 100, 300, 15, 555, 900]
Y = [500.5, 500, 600.5, 100, 8, 555, 999]

def get_indices(values):
    d = defaultdict(set)
    for i, value in enumerate(values):
        d[value].add(i)
    return d

iA, iB, iX, iY = [get_indices(values) for values in [A, B, X, Y]]
print(iA)
# {400.5: {0}, 100: {1}, 200: {3}, 900: {5}, 700: {2}, 15: {4}}
print(iX)
# {400.5: {0}, 100: {2}, 300: {3}, 900: {6}, 555: {5}, 700: {1}, 15: {4}}

for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(A, B)):
    common_indices = iX[a] & iY[b]
    if common_indices:
        print("A B : %d" % i)
        print("X Y : %d" % common_indices.pop())
        print()

#   A B : 0
#   X Y : 0

#   A B : 2
#   X Y : 1

#   A B : 4
#   X Y : 4

#   A B : 5
#   X Y : 6
```